# Prove that every algebraic extensions over $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Prove that every algebraic extensions over $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$

Corollary $3.20$ page $267$ of Hungerford - Algebra: "Every proper algebraic extension field  of the field of real numbers is isomorphic to the field of complex numbers.". Does it equivalent to the truth that I want to prove?

Comment: Yes, the claims are equivalent. As a hint to prove it, start by considering a proper extension - it has to contain an element $a + bi$ with $b \ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Comment: Alternatively, $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}] = 2$, and $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so any proper algebraic extension $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ must be contained in $\mathbb{C}$, and so $[K:\mathbb{R}]$ must divide 2.